# Problems with configuration of SVN ( error code 500 )

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, ssl

I posted similar thread recently, but I was on hurry, so I didn't provide any necessary information. I followed arch-linux wiki guide for setting up a SVN repository using apache and ssl. I'm almost certain, that I understand all the steps, and that I filled them correctly. Here is the guide: 
`https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Subversion_Setup`.
When I try to connect using

```
svn co https://192.168.0.21/svn/myrepo
```

or

```
links https://192.168.0.21/svn/myrepo
```

the http authentication asks me to fill my account's name and password. After the form (no matter if name and password are correct), there's a message:

`Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request for https://192.168.0.21/svn/myrepo`

I checked httpd/errors_log, and every time I try to connect, apache outputs:

```
[Thu Nov 29 22:19:45 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.21] (13)Permission denied: Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: Can't open file '/home/svn/.svn-policy-file': Permission denied
[Thu Nov 29 22:19:57 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.21] (13)Permission denied: Could not open password file: /home/svn/.svn-auth-file
```

But here's my ls -la on /home/svn

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 http http    40 Nov 29 16:02 .svn-auth-file
-rwxrwxrwx 1 http http    43 Nov 29 17:58 .svn-policy-file
```

I ran even 777 on them, so I just don't have a clue what causes the problem. Thanks for help in advance :)

@Lazy Badger
Here's my /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf part related to ssl, it's in virtual hosts section

```
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /home/svn/repositories
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/svn/.svn-policy-file
   AuthName "SVN Repositories"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /home/svn/.svn-auth-file
   Satisfy Any
   Require valid-user
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Changing to un-dotted configs does not change anything :/

Saying it's outside the jail you mean it's not in /etc/httpd/conf or /srv/http ? I think it's not the problem, the path is absolute.

Comment: 1. Don't use dotted files now 2. Can your Apache be chrooted and files these outside jail? 3. Show subversion-related `<Location>`

Comment: @LazyBadger I updated above post, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Set permissions also on the folder, that contains files svn-policy and svn-auth.

`chown http /home/svn -R`